# Different value of JNDI parameter for different standalone instances in GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish

I need to have the same application deployed in GlassFish several times, with different JNDI parameters, but I can't find a way to do that.

I know I can have different standalone instances and apply the different JNDI resources to one or several instances, but I can't have the same resource name with different values for the different instances.
What is the way to achieve what I need?

Comment: What do you mean by different JNDI _parameters_? Is it like additional properties passed into a JNDI, i.e, property.value='value1', property.value='value2', or different JNDI value like JNDI1, JNDI2, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end what I did is to use this:

```
   @Resource(lookup = "java:app/AppName")
   private String appName;

   private String myJndiParameter;
```

And then since I can't use a variable to get the custom jndi parameter in an annotation, I created a @PostConstruct method, where I get the jndi value that I want, something like this:

```
   @PostConstruct
   public void initialize ()
   {
      try
      {
         myJndiParameter = (String) new javax.naming.InitialContext().lookup(appName + "/" + "my.jndi.parameter.name");
      } catch (NamingException e)
      {
         // Treat exception
      }
   }
```

In GlassFish, my custom resource name looks like:

```
myapp/my.jndi.parameter.name
```

I'm open to suggestions to improve it :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the requirement, you can use different JNDI configurations in a property file and pass the values in JVM arguments to apply each configuration to several glassfish server instances.

Comment: I am sorry I haven't been able to work on this much since something came up, but the bounty was about to expire. I believe your idea is more what I need, would you mind providing an example of how would you configure it in GlassFish and how would the properties file look? If you do and works I will also accept your answer

Comment: Sure. Let me provide the example ASAP.